# How to exchange data between shell/Python and web pages?

Tags: python, shell, web

I need to provide an interface with a device through web pages. In details:

- It should enable fetching/sending data from/to the device with using shell commands or Python APIs (either one works).
- The data from the device should be updated on web pages dynamically as long as new values are returned by shell commands/Python APIs.
- Good to have: being able to define which data to fetch/send.

Which framework should I pick for this purpose concerning the difficulty? I have been mostly working on hardware and drivers with some experience with Python/shell. I don't know much about web yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Opinion here... I have been very happy with flask. It allows me to read and write web pages but seems, at least to me, easier to learn than Django. Further, I use SQLAlchemy for DB access if that's important.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the input.